# Jquery fadeIn() affected by CSS transition

Tags: jquery, css, transition, fadein

im having a problem where i call a fade in when the website loads but due to the css transition effect the element goes to full opacity instantly fades out then fades back in, im trying to find a way around this as it looks bad

jQuery

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#contactbutton').fadeIn(2000);
}, 4000);
```

HTML

```
<div class="contactbutton" style="display:none;" id="contactbutton">CONTACT</div>
```

CSS

```
.contactbutton {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:25px;
    width:160px;
    color:#e97861;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    line-height:37px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:9999;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `transition` property in your css?

Comment: @Al.G. Transition doesn't work on `display`.

Comment: apologize it was there but when i deleted it it worked as it should ill add it again now

Comment: i need it to be there but it doesnt work properly when it is

Comment: If it doesn't work, why do you use `transition`? What do you need it for?

Comment: because i need to have a transition on the element after it has faded in for mouse overs

Comment: Which properties do you need "transitioned"? Don't say "all" .5s", but rather "color" or "background" or whatever...

Comment: not to worry ive put a timout out on and added the transition property after it has faded in all fixed but yet im sure that would work too

Answer (score 0):

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okahara/4ho2s4eh/2/) with your code and made a few edits so that the fade works on load.

The css `transition: all .5s` was throwing off the transition you were trying to do with Javascript. You were also using an unnecessary class but if you really want it you can add it back.

HTML

```
<div id="contactbutton">CONTACT</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contactbutton').fadeIn(2000);
})
```

CSS

```
#contactbutton {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #e97861;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 37px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10px;
  width: 160px;
```

}